# error RC2104: undefined keyword or key name: WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL

Tags: winapi, resources

I'm designing an RTL dialog in VS 2012, and I've stumbled upon the following error:

> error RC2104: undefined keyword or key name: WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL

Googling for it gave zero results, which is quite rare.

Any ideas what's the problem and how can it be solved?

Defining WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL in the .rc dialog fixes it, as well as replacing WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL with 0x00400000L, but of course these solutions don't really work as the .rc file is auto generated and the changes are lost.

Comment: May be this MS Dev Center article helps a bit: [How to Ensure Text is Displayed with the Correct Reading Direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee264314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You must set the [target Windows version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) correctly, WINVER must be at least 0x0500.

Comment: I have WINVER defined in stdafx.h, but it seems to not have effect on the .rc file. Defining WINVER in the .rc file makes it work, but that's not a solution. ... While typing the comment, I found out that WINVER should be included in the Process Definitions for resources, which is a separate tab in the solution properties. You might want to post it as an answer so I'll accept it.

Comment: OK, I still have an issue. The code compiles now, but I cannot reopen the dialog in the resource designer. It still shows the same error message (undefined WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL). Any ideas?

Comment: If you add the `#define` to the `TEXTINCLUDE` section of the resource file it will survive auto-generation. It's an odd problem though, I just tried setting that flag in one of my dialogs and it worked fine, and my resource files don't seem to have `WINVER` defined anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanPotter. That's actually how I solved it, too, before seeing your comment. [Here's a minimal project](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/4xqjPCu/0/blob?download) that demonstrates the issue. VS has an option to create a new project from a template (with a window etc.), which doesn't suffer from the issue as it includes a "targetver.h" file [in it's `TEXTINCLUDE`](http://i.snag.gy/RzC4g.jpg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: you should define the appropriate `WINVER` value in your .rc file. As the .rc file is auto generated by the resource editor, you cannot just define it anywhere because it will be overwritten. You can use [the `TEXTINCLUDE` section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t3612sk.aspx) to prevent it from getting overwritten.

Example (line 5):

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#define WINVER 0x0500 // <-- ADDED
#include "afxres.h"
```

And (line 3):

```
2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#define WINVER 0x0500 // <-- ADDED\r\n"
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END
```